# Java representation of HTML object

Tags: java, html, paint

I am trying to find some java code that would represent the display of a set of HTML objects (i.e. this code would go in the paint function). This is to go into a home built IDE f ro HTML and javascript (I can't use a ready made version, for complicated reasons)

I can't use images to represent the HTML objects, as the properties (border color, etc) all need to be changeable.

In short, I require the code that could be used in the paint method of a HTML component.

Does anyone have any idea where I could get this? Or an idea of how to do it. I just tried to hand write the code to represent a select tag, and its very difficult.

EDIT:
It turns out (as stated below) that what I am looking for is a HTML renderer. However, the code that I have is javascript, that is interpreted as HTML by a browser. The following code is that generated by the IDE, I have a way of accessing the properties that will be required (borderColor, etc) what I require is a way to render these onto a JPanel. i.e. How can I draw a red box onto the JPanel that represents the DIV below (simple example, I can do this, but need the same for a large subset (preferrably all) css properties):

```
function componentName(constructor, properties){
this.style = {}
this.style.left = 0; //@property TYPE_TEXT left
this.style.top = 0; //@property TYPE_TEXT top
this.style.width = 100; //@property TYPE_TEXT width
this.style.height = 50; //@property TYPE_TEXT height
this.body0 = document.body
this.body0.onmousedown = this.this.body0_onmousedown
this.body0.style.borderStyle = ""
this.body0.style.borderWidth = "0px"
this.body0.style.overflow = "auto"
this.body0.style.top = "0px"
this.body0.style.left = "0px"
this.body0.style.position = "fixed"
this.body0.name = ""
this.body0.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"
this.body0.onmousedown = this.body0_onmousedown
this.body0.style.width = "296px"
this.body0.style.height = "193px"
this.DIV0 = document.createElement("DIV")
this.DIV0.style.height = "216px"
this.DIV0.style.width = "181px"
this.DIV0.onmousedown = this.DIV0_onmousedown
this.DIV0.style.top = "40px"
this.DIV0.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"
...etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Java DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html).  For example, there is an [`Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) interface.  There are multiple concrete implementations, including [`IIOMetadataNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataNode.html)

Comment: Thanks, but these don't have any paint code method, what I require is a way of graphically representing an element, i.e. an input element, or select element.

Comment: @ZackNewsham, are you looking for a Java [HTML renderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_engine), or what?  That's different from just representing the tag.

Comment: yes I think that may have been a better way of describing it, although now an additional "wrinkle" is that the code that is generated is in fact javascript, which browsers convert to HTML... I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I searched on google for "Java HTML Renderer" and found this: http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp. Maybe that would help? It (from the website) supports HTML4, Javascript, and CSS2.

Comment: This looks like it might be good, thanks! I am currently trawling through their code trying to find where the actual painting takes place.